# Начало перемещения объекта из случайно выбранной точки path SVG

Tags: javascript, css, html5, svg, анимация

Я пытаюсь получить некоторое представление о SVG. Есть ли способ перемещения круга по `path` SVG, где круг начинает двигаться из определенной точки, определяемой длиной пути?

Например, когда объект достигает конца, он начинается снова с самого начала.

Какие атрибуты использовать, чтобы заставить круг перемещаться из случайной точки, например, начиная с 20, а не с 0 до 100?

В SVG есть прямой способ - `from` и `to`, но я не уверен, как правильно его использовать. Кроме того, я обнаружил, что в некоторых случаях использование `keytimes` может быть полезным, но оно не дало желаемого результата.

Здесь можете увидеть HTML-код SVG, движущийся по пути, где он начинается с начала:

```html
  <div id="pathContainer4">
   <svg height="160" width="360">
  <g fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1">
    <path stroke-dasharray="3" id="motionpath2"
     d="M 10 80 C 40 10, 65 10, 95 80 S 150 150, 180 80" />
  </g>
              <circle class="circle2" r=8 fill=red ;z-index=55>
              
             <animateMotion dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite"
     rotate="auto"  from="20" to="100">
                 <mpath href="#motionpath2" />
             </animateMotion>
         </circle>
  </svg>
  </div>
```

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/59291368/7394871

Answer (score 4):

> В SVG есть прямой способ from и to, но я не уверен, как правильно его
>   использовать. Кроме того, я обнаружил, что в некоторых случаях
>   использование keytimes может быть полезным, но оно не дало желаемого
>   результата.

Возможно запустить анимацию SVG, не используя JS, из любой точки траектории , но её положение должно быть определено заранее в коде .

Для этого используется пара атрибутов

```
keyPoints="0;1" - движение от начала  пути до конца
keyTimes="0;1"
```

```
keyPoints="0.5;1" - движение с середины пути до конца
keyTimes="0;1"
```

```
keyPoints="1;0" - движение от конца пути до начала
keyTimes="0;1"
```

Так можно управлять положением начальной точки анимации, но
теоретически невозможно создать анимацию из рандомно выбранной точки, поскольку в SVG нет переменных, нет массивов, нет инструкций для хранения и выполнения математических функций.

*В примере ниже JS используется только для обработки события нажатия кнопок управления:*

```html
<div id="pathContainer4">
  <button id="btn1" onclick="forwardSVG()">forward</button />
  <button id="btn2" onclick="middleSVG()">Middle</button />
  <button id="btn3" onclick="backSVG()">Back</button />
</div> 
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" height="160" width="360" >
  <g fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1">
    <path stroke-dasharray="3" id="motionpath2"
     d="M 10 80 C 40 10, 65 10, 95 80 S 150 150, 180 80" />
  </g>
   <circle class="circle2" r=8 fill=red ;z-index=55>
              
  <animateMotion
    id="forward"
    dur="2s"
    begin="indefinite"
    repeatCount="1"
    keyPoints="0;1"
    keyTimes="0;1"
       calcMode="linear"    >
   <mpath href="#motionpath2" />
  </animateMotion> 
  <animateMotion
     id="middle"
     dur="2s"
     begin="indefinite"
     repeatCount="1"
     keyPoints="0.5;1"
     keyTimes="0;1"
     calcMode="linear"     >
   <mpath href="#motionpath2" />
     </animateMotion> 
     <animateMotion
     id="back"
     dur="2s"
     begin="indefinite"
     repeatCount="1"
     keyPoints="1;0"
     keyTimes="0;1"
     calcMode="linear"     >
   <mpath href="#motionpath2" />
     </animateMotion>
         </circle>
  </svg>
  
<script>
var animation1 = document.getElementById("forward")
function forwardSVG(){
     animation1.beginElement();
} 
var animation2 = document.getElementById("middle")
function middleSVG(){
     animation2.beginElement();
}  

var animation3 = document.getElementById("back")
function backSVG(){
     animation3.beginElement();
}
</script>
```

Вы также можете  создать иллюзию случайного движения.

**Пример с иллюзией случайного движения бильярдных шаров**

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" height="100vh" viewBox="0 0 400 400">

<rect width="100%" height="100%" rx="25"  fill="green" stroke="#9D8500" stroke-width="15"/>
<circle cx="50%" cy="20%" r="3%" fill="url(#gradB)" >

 <animate attributeName="cx" dur="3" values="3%;97%;3%"  
   repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
 <animate attributeName="cy" dur="2.8" values="3%;97%;3%"  
   repeatCount="indefinite" />
</circle>

<circle cx="30%" cy="70%" r="3%" fill="url(#gradR)" >

 <animate attributeName="cx" dur="2.7" values="97%;3%;97%"  
   repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
 <animate attributeName="cy" dur="3.1" values="3%;97%;3%"  
   repeatCount="indefinite" />
</circle>

 <radialGradient id="gradB" cx="20%" cy="20%" r="100%" fx="30%" fy="30%">
   <stop stop-color="white" offset="0"/>
   <stop stop-color="blue" offset="25%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(0,0,192)" offset="50%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(0,0,127)" offset="70%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(0,0,64)" offset="85%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(0,0,0)" offset="100%"/>
 </radialGradient>

 <radialGradient id="gradR" cx="20%" cy="20%" r="100%" fx="30%" fy="30%">
   <stop stop-color="white" offset="0"/>
   <stop stop-color="red" offset="25%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(192,0,0)" offset="50%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(127,0,0)" offset="70%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(64,0,0)" offset="85%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(0,0,0)" offset="100%"/>
 </radialGradient>

</svg>
```

**Ещё несколько примеров иллюзии хаотического движения букв без JS**

```html
</style>
<svg width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" 
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" baseProfile="tiny"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
 
 <title>Animation of text x and y attributes</title> 
 

<defs>
<linearGradient id="grad"
    x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="100%"
    gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <stop offset="2%" stop-color="steelblue" />
        <stop offset="45%" stop-color="hsla(180, 100%, 50%, 0)" />
        <stop offset="45%" stop-color="hsla(80, 100%, 50%, 0)" />
        <stop offset="95%" stop-color="yellowgreen" />
    </linearGradient>
</defs> 
 <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#grad)" />
<text  x="200 " y="500" 
font-size="90" fill="#E4E4E4" stroke-width="4" stroke="#E4E4E4">Stackoverflow</text> 
<text id="text1" x="200" y="500"
font-size="90">Stackoverflow</text> 

<animate xlink:href="#text1" 
 attributeName="x" 
 attributeType="XML"
        values="200 233 266 299 332 365 400 431 464 497 530 563 596;
 100 600 200 365 700 465 465 563 530 398 431 850 900; 
 200 500 900 950 150 531 300 620 150 266 365 650 900;
 332 233 820 300 800 633 200 670 300 850 800 530 266;
 464 900 900 900 820 670 430 900 530 600 233 365 100;
 332 100 100 100 500 100 800 563 900 700 900 100 100;
  200 233 266 299 332 365 400 431 464 497 530 563 596"
 dur="4s"
 begin="0s"
 repeatCount="2" />
<animate xlink:href="#text1"
 attributeName="y" 
 attributeType="XML"
        values="500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500;
 100 200 850 100 250 175 750 100 750 720 850 500 50; 
 100 600 600 250 200 450 50 200 520 550 300 300 750;
 500 100 650 650 600 150 550 50 150 550 200 550 400; 
 800 300 100 750 150 650 75 350 550 700 755 120 800;
 800 600 300 150 750 350 700 650 200 250 500 650 100;
 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500"
 dur="4s"
 begin="0s"
 repeatCount="2" />


</svg>
```

**Вертикальная парковка букв**

```html
<style>
 #text1 {

fill:#B2000C;
}
 
</style>
<svg width="70%" height="70%" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" 
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" baseProfile="tiny"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
 
 <title>Animation of text x and y attributes</title> 
 

<defs>
<linearGradient id="grad"
    x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="100%"
    gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <stop offset="2%" stop-color="steelblue" />
        <stop offset="45%" stop-color="hsla(180, 100%, 50%, 0)" />
        <stop offset="45%" stop-color="hsla(80, 100%, 50%, 0)" />
        <stop offset="95%" stop-color="yellowgreen" />
    </linearGradient>
</defs> 
 <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#grad)" />
<text  x="200 " y="500" 
font-size="90" fill="#E4E4E4" stroke-width="4" stroke="#E4E4E4">Stackoverflow</text> 
<text id="text1" x="200" y="500"
font-size="90">Stackoverflow</text> 

<animate xlink:href="#text1" 
 attributeName="x" 
 attributeType="XML"
        values="200 233 266 299 332 365 400 431 464 497 530 563 596;
 100 600 200 365 700 465 465 563 530 398 431 850 900; 
 200 500 900 950 150 531 300 620 150 266 365 650 900;
 332 233 820 300 800 633 200 670 300 850 800 530 266;
 464 900 900 900 820 670 430 900 530 600 233 365 100;
 332 100 100 100 500 100 800 563 900 700 900 100 100;
    200 233 266 299 332 365 400 431 464 497 530 563 596"
 dur="3s"
 begin="0s"
 repeatCount="2" />
<animate xlink:href="#text1"
 attributeName="y" 
 attributeType="XML"
        values="500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500;
 100 200 850 100 250 175 750 100 750 720 850 500 50; 
 100 600 600 250 200 450 50 200 520 550 300 300 750;
 500 100 650 650 600 150 550 50 150 550 200 550 400; 
 800 300 100 750 150 650 75 350 550 700 755 120 800;
 800 600 300 150 750 350 700 650 200 250 500 650 100;
 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500"
 dur="4s"
 begin="0s"
 repeatCount="2" />


</svg>
```

**Горизонтальная парковка букв**

```html
<style>
 #text1 {

fill:#B2000C;
}
 
</style>
<svg width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" 
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" baseProfile="tiny"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
 
 <title>Animation of text x and y attributes</title> 
 

<defs>
<linearGradient id="grad"
    x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="100%"
    gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <stop offset="2%" stop-color="steelblue" />
        <stop offset="45%" stop-color="hsla(180, 100%, 50%, 0)" />
        <stop offset="45%" stop-color="hsla(80, 100%, 50%, 0)" />
        <stop offset="95%" stop-color="yellowgreen" />
    </linearGradient>
</defs> 
 <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#grad)" />
<text  x="200 " y="500" 
font-size="90" fill="#E4E4E4" stroke-width="4" stroke="#E4E4E4">Stackoverflow</text> 
<text id="text1" x="200" y="500"
font-size="90">Stackoverflow</text> 

<animate xlink:href="#text1" 
   attributeName="x" 
   attributeType="XML"
    values="200 233 266 299 332 365 400 431 464 497 530 563 596;
 100 600 200 365 700 465 465 563 530 398 431 850 900; 
 200 500 900 950 150 531 300 620 150 266 365 650 900;
 332 233 820 300 800 633 200 670 300 850 800 530 266;
 464 900 900 900 820 670 430 900 530 600 233 365 100;
 332 100 100 100 500 100 800 563 900 700 900 100 100;
    200 233 266 299 332 365 400 431 464 497 530 563 596"
 dur="4s"
 begin="0s"
 repeatCount="2" />
<animate xlink:href="#text1"
   attributeName="y" 
   attributeType="XML"
    values="500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500;
 100 200 850 100 250 175 750 100 750 720 850 500 50; 
 100 600 600 250 200 450 50 200 520 550 300 300 750;
 500 100 650 650 600 150 550 50 150 550 200 550 400; 
 800 300 100 750 150 650 75 350 550 700 755 120 800;
 800 600 300 150 750 350 700 650 200 250 500 650 100;
 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500"
     dur="3s"
   begin="0s"
     repeatCount="2" />


</svg>
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59293886/7394871): @Alexandr_TT

Comment: Саша салам! А как сделать что бы точка стояла на линии ?

Comment: @ MaximLensky Задай большое время анимации dur="1000m"

Comment: ты не меня, в твоём примере этот косяк

Comment: @MaximLensky в чем выражается косяк? Chrome, FF, Opera, Yandex полет нормальный, мелкософт не понимает анимацию